# How can I mock PagedResultList in grails 2.2.4

Tags: grails, groovy, mocking, hibernate-criteria

Seems that PagedResultList is changed in grails 2.2.4 which is causing some issues in unit test.

The constructor is changed from

```
PagedResultList(list())
```

to

```
PagedResultList(GrailsHibernateTemplate template, Criteria crit)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this...

```
def mockC = mockFor(org.hibernate.Criteria) 
mockC.demand.list { return []} //PagedResultList constructor calls this
def pagedList = new PagedResultList(null, mockC.createMock()){
    {
       //Using a static block to set private variables 
       //since we can't call a constructor here!
       list = yourList
       totalCount = yourList.size()
    }
}
```

Comment: perfect. Can you please elaborate //Using a static block to set private variables //since we can't call a constructor here!. Also did you use 2 brackets {{ intentionally?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - had the last } missing - updated now. Static block because you can't call a constructor of an inner class.

Answer (score 2):

If only care about return values, attach `totalCount` to `ArrayList`.

```
def list = [domainObj1, domainObj2]
list.metaClass.getTotalCount {
    2
}
```